# ORA-01791-Distinct and order by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by, distinct

I want to get the distinct `"SkillCategory"` and sort by `id`

here is the script below :

```
SELECT  distinct EC.SKILL_CATEGORY from ETOPS_CHECK_FORM E
INNER JOIN EC_FORM_SKILL EC
ON EC.EC_FORM_ID=E.ID group by EC.SKILL_CATEGORY ORDER BY EC.ID
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need to decide *which* id to sort by.  Remove the `distinct` and then use an aggregation function in the `order by`:

```
SELECT EC.SKILL_CATEGORY
FROM ETOPS_CHECK_FORM E INNER JOIN
     EC_FORM_SKILL EC
     ON EC.EC_FORM_ID = E.ID
GROUP BY EC.SKILL_CATEGORY
ORDER BY MIN(EC.ID);
```

Comment: sorry that one works for me this is the works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want distinct records with no use of aggregate functions then use **DISTINCT** keyword instead of **GROUP BY**

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EC.SKILL_CATEGORY 
FROM ETOPS_CHECK_FORM E
INNER JOIN EC_FORM_SKILL EC ON EC.EC_FORM_ID = E.ID 
ORDER BY EC.ID;
```

Comment: It cannot work. Oracle have no clue to how to sort it using key2, when it had already made a distinct with key1..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  distinct EC.SKILL_CATEGORY 
FROM ETOPS_CHECK_FORM E
  INNER JOIN EC_FORM_SKILL EC
          ON EC.EC_FORM_ID=E.ID 
GROUP BY EC.SKILL_CATEGORY ASC
ORDER BY MAX(EC.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wonder what you really want to do... ^^
But, if you run the script bellow, could you tell us if the result is what you hope:

```
Select ec.skill_category as sc
from EC_FORM_SKILL ec
group by sc;
```

See you later.

Comment: that script doesnt sort it am i right. It should be sorted by id

Comment: so sort by ec.id. But you need to return this one in the select ;)